# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first on Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Here is the Code, i am adding AlertDialog and calling it on close

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setView(mview)
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton("No",null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            finish();
                    }
                }).show();
```

When i click back for second time the application crashes

Comment: please provide us with activity code and log error

Comment: How are you creating or finding mview? If you are inflating from XML, you'll need to make sure that it is not added to a ViewGroup by calling LayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.foo,null).

Comment: After re-reading, it sounds like you are re-using mview between instances of the AlertDialog.Builder. If you are inflating it from XML, re-inflate the view each time and don't reuse the same instance.

Comment: thank you all 
I have found the solution
By making AlertDialog.Builder(this) instance and then using it to show it again if (mview.getParent()!=null) alertdialog.show();